# Java getting functions from Object type

Tags: java

I have

```
 public Object get(int index)
    {
        if (index <= 0)
            return null;

        Node Current = head.getNext();
        for (int i = 1; i < index; i++) {
            if (Current.getNext() == null)
                return null;

            Current = Current.getNext();
        }
        return Current.getData();
    }
```

this method for a linked list to get something in an index. That something is a Painting object, and I want to get the title of the painting using a getTitle method within the Painting class.

Here is what I tried to do,

```
for(int i = 0; i < paintings.size(); i++){
        Painting x = (Painting) paintings.get(i);
        System.out.println((i+1) + ": " + x.getTitle());
}
```

Unfortunately at x.getTitle() java gets extremely salty and gives a null pointer exception. I've tried multiple ways of doing this with different casts and I'm just personally lost. Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: why don't u show us the `getTitle()` method ?

Comment: @blackSmith that's not needed here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have a validation since `x` can be `null`. When `x=null`, `x.getTitle()` become `null.getTitle()` which cause `NullPointerException`.

```
 Painting x = (Painting) paintings.get(i);
 System.out.println((i+1) + ": " + (x!=null?x.getTitle():"x is null"));
```

Comment: Actually I've realized my real issue was that my linkedlist's first index is actually 1 instead of 0, but this also helps incase the linked list is empty and the user prints out the contents of it so thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning `null` if nothing is present at that index, and then doing `x(null).getTitle()` causing `NullPointerException`.

Just add a null check before calling the method.